# Can't add a LinearProgressIndicator correctly in flutter

Tags: flutter

In my flutter app, I have a price objective to reach and I have the current price variables. I would like to show a LinearProgressIndicator to display these 2 values but i'm always getting the following error:

> Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was LinearProgressIndicator
> Also, it directly opens the `double.dart` file.
> I tried setting null condition on the value property of LinearProgressIndicator but still getting errors, any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
  double sum = 0.0;
  double goal = 0.0;
  double currentPrice = 0.0;

  void getType() {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) {
      if (this.mounted) {
        setState(() {
          userType = data.data()!['type'];
          updateOperationsList();
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('interventions')
              .where('userId', isEqualTo: user!.uid)
              .get()
              .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
            double sum = 0.0;
            querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
              sum += (doc['prix']).toDouble();
            });

            setState(() {
              currentPrice = sum;
            });
            print('Total Price: ${currentPrice.toStringAsFixed(2)} €');
            if (userType == "Salarié") {
              setState(() {
                goal = 6000;
              });
            } else if (userType == "Auto entrepreneur") {
              setState(() {
                goal = 10000;
              });
            }
            print('Goal: ${goal.toStringAsFixed(2)} €');
            if (userType == "Salarié" && currentPrice < goal) {
              print('salarié goal not reached');
            } else if (userType == "Auto entrepreneur" && currentPrice < goal) {
              print('auto goal not reached');
            } else if (userType == "Salarié" && currentPrice >= goal) {
              print('salarié goal reached');
            } else if (userType == "Auto entrepreneur" &&
                currentPrice >= goal) {
              print('auto goal reached');
            }

            print('GOAL: $goal');
            print('PRICE: $currentPrice');
            print('SUM: $sum');
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }

  void updateOperationsList() {
    setState(() {
      operations = userType == "Salarié"
          ? <Item>[
              Item(Icons.bar_chart, 'Interventions'),
              Item(Icons.money, 'Mes BPUs'),
              Item(Icons.file_copy, 'Docs Salarié'),
              Item(Icons.article, 'Docs Entrep'),
              Item(Icons.monetization_on, 'Factures'),
              Item(Icons.discount, 'Réçus'),
            ]
          : <Item>[
              Item(Icons.bar_chart, 'Interventions'),
              Item(Icons.money, 'Mes BPUs'),
              Item(Icons.file_copy, 'Docs Auto'),
              Item(Icons.article, 'Docs Entrep'),
              Item(Icons.monetization_on, 'Factures'),
              Item(Icons.discount, 'Réçus'),
            ];
    });
  }

  Future<double> getCurrentPrice() async {
    double sum = 0.0;

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('interventions')
        .where('userId', isEqualTo: user!.uid)
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
        sum += (doc['prix']).toDouble();
      });
    });

    return sum;
  }

  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshIndicatorKey =
      GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

  Future<void> _refresh() async {
    double price = await getCurrentPrice();

    setState(() {
      currentPrice = price;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkUser();
    getData();
    getType();
    updateOperationsList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.logout,
                color: style.appColor,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                Authent().logOut();
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()));
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
        onRefresh: _refresh,
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) => ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildUserInfo(),
              _buildTitleRow('Société', 'Détails Profile'),
              _buildOverview(),
              _buildTitleRow('Opérations', ''),
              GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                crossAxisSpacing: 16,
                mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                children: operations!.map((e) {
                  return _buildSingleOperation(e);
                }).toList(),
              ),
              _buildTitleRow('Objectifs', ''),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                decoration: whiteBox(),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '${((currentPrice / goal) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0)}% Complétés',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'medium'),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Les chiffres de récap',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16),
                    LinearProgressIndicator(
                      value: currentPrice / goal,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(style.appColor),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The problem occurs with this part:

```
LinearProgressIndicator(
                          value: currentPrice / goal,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
                          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(style.appColor),
                        )
```

Thanks in advance!